Sci Fi film with Woman Alien
Hello I am looking for a sci-fi alien invasion film, but I can only remember the ending: 
A city is being overrun by some aliens and people are trying to escape, possibly due to the fact that the humans did not come to an agreement with the aliens. 
The main actor, a man (around 40-50?) finally sacrifices himself by going to a building to see the Alien queen (she has a normal human woman's body shape with blue-ish grey skin with a big tail, I think). the queen is actually in love with him so he went there to ask her to stop. She was in a place where she was connected to something and commanding the whole alien war with her will power. 
The man cuddles with the queen and I suppose they must have kissed. He had a big knife and he stabbed her from the back and the knife went through her and also stabbed through to his body. She looked at him in astonishment but eventually they both died together. Hence the war outside ends while they are both dead. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Thanks for the detailed description of the scene that you can remember - hopefully we can help! Is there any chance you can remember any non-plot-related elements? For instance, when did you watch it (last month, last year...) and/or when do you think it may have come out ('80s, '90s, '00s...)? What language was it in and/or what country was it from? You can add in this kind of information by clicking the "edit" button below your post. Thanks!

This sounds somewhat like the ending of Lifeforce (1985) although some of the details differ. 
From Wikipedia:

Carlsen impales himself and the female alien simultaneously. The female vampire is only wounded and returns to her ship with Carlsen in tow, releasing a burst of energy that blows open the cupoladome of St. Paul's. 


Thank you! I think I must have dreamt that alien outlook up! I just watch a clip on youtube it is indeed the movie i had been looking for! :-)
